# Как добавить атрибут в input в Django admin-панеле

Tags: django, django-admin

собственно сабж. Интересует, как добавить что-то вроде title или может какой-то data-attribute, в input'ы редактируемой сущности.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно статическое значение, то можно перегрузить `Meta.widgets` формы и задать виджет с нужными атрибутами для поля:

```
class SomeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    model = MyModel

    Meta:
        widgets = {
            'some_field': forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-something': 'some value'}
        }
```

Чтобы какое-то динамическое значение задавать нужно перегрузить метод `__init__` формы и там инициализировать виджеты:

```
class SomeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['some_field'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'data-something': self.instance.get_some_value()})
```

Comment: В какие файлы этот код лучше класть?

Comment: @ashalbulk формы обычно в `forms.py`

Comment: сделал всё, как Вы сказали, но не работает. Обратил внимание, что он вообще не видит forms.py. Мне кажется, что надо где-то в настройках прописать что-то, чтобы django этот файл начал использовать. Погуглил, но ничего не нашел(

Comment: @ashalbulk чтобы админка подхватила форму нужно ее указать в [ModelAdmin](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.8.x/ref/contrib/admin/index.html#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)

Comment: не, не сработало, он просто не видит forms.py. В ide подсвечивает красным класс формы в ModelAdmin и даёт 502. А если Я прописываю какую-то ересь в forms.py ничего не происходит, ошибок не даёт. Следовательно, Я пришел к тому. что он просто не подключен, сам файл. Django 1.8

Comment: @ashalbulk import нужно добавить естественно

Comment: Не выходит. 502 и всё тут. Хотя импорт прописал. Я прочитал доку которую Вы бросали, но мне кажется Я что-то делаю не так. И ещё не могу понять, зачем нужен exclude = ['age']. Свой код из ModelAdmin, который касается формы:   
from django_project.forms import GalleryAdminForm     form = GalleryAdminForm

Comment: сама форма:  `from django import forms
from django_project.models import Gallery


class GalleryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Gallery

    class Meta:
        fields = ('title', 'dateTime', 'short_content', 'content', ('image', 'image_img', 'image_img_thumb'))
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.CharField(attrs={'data-something': 'some value'})
        }`

Comment: может Я закрою вопрос и мы обсудим это в скайпе. Думаю всё дело в моих знаниях, думаю, что тем кому понадобится Вы уже помогли отписав сюда. Мой скайп crashow3r